# Excel VBA - Shape placement behaviour with groups

Tags: vba, excel

I have a number of Groups and buttons attached to a pivot table. I want to set all of these to NOT move and size with cells. I am using the code below to accomplish this. This works fine for Groups but does not access the buttons within the groups.

These buttons are within a nested group. How can I access the buttons within these groups?

I've tried

```
Sheet1.Shapes.SelectAll
Selection.UnGroup
```

.. at the start of the code to clear all groups. This allows me to update the buttons nested in the groups. How would I code this differently to access the buttons within the various groups without first clearing all the groups on the page?

```
Group 26          (A group containing slicers and buttons)
  Group box 28    (A Form Control Group Box)
   Group 24       (A Grouping of the buttons)
      btn_do_this
      btn_do_that
```

Any ideas??

```
Private Sub Cmd_Move_and_size_Click()
Dim sh As Shape
Dim StrText As String
For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
  '  If sh.Type = 12 Then sh.Visible = True 'show button!
   ' Debug.Print (CStr(sh.Type) + " " + sh.Name
   StrText = " Shape will not move and size with cells"
    If sh.Placement <> xlFreeFloating Then
       sh.Placement = xlFreeFloating
       Else
       sh.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
       StrText = " Shape WILL move and size with cells"
    End If
Next
MsgBox StrText
End Sub
```